# Compare dates in different, unequal data sets and adding value for a given date range

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, date-comparison

I'm trying to compare two time series datasets. One of the dataset has sets of time ranges (event start and end times)and a value. The second dataset has time range (frequency = 1 hour) from Minimum of start time to max end time of dataset1. I want to add a value to those whose time range match.

Example:

Dataset 1, imported as pandas dataframe and dates are parsed:

```
data1:
Start_Time       |     End_Time        | Value

01/01/2017 13:00   01/01/2017 16:00      68
01/02/2017 00:00   01/02/2017 08:00      70
01/03/2017 10:00   01/03/2017 17:00      90
```

Dataset 2 is created using pandas date_range

```
data2['date'] = pd.date_range(start=data1['Start_Time'].min(), 
                            end = data1['End_Time'].max(), freq = '1H')
```

I tried using `np.where` to find the date range satisfying the condition

**Note:** Both DataFrames are of unequal size

```
data2['Value'] = np.where((data1['Start_Time']>=data2['date'][data1.index]) 
                  & (data1['End_time']<=data2['date'][data1.index]),
                  data1['Value'], 0)
```

What I need data2 dataframe to be is

```
Date             | Value
01/01/2017 13:00   68
01/01/2017 14:00   68
01/01/2017 15:00   68
01/01/2017 16:00   68
01/01/2017 17:00   0
01/01/2017 18:00   0
.
.
.
.
01/02/2017 00:00   70
01/02/2017 01:00   70
01/02/2017 02:00   70
and so on.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `numpy` broadcast which is o(m*n) method

```
#data1.Start_Time=pd.to_datetime(data1.Start_Time)
#data1.End_Time=pd.to_datetime(data1.End_Time)
s1=data1.Start_Time.values
s2=data1.End_Time.values
s=data2.date.values
a=np.dot((s[:,None]>=s1)&(s[:,None]<=s2),data1.Value.values)
Out[639]: 
array([68, 68, 68, 68,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70, 70,
       70, 70, 70,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90,
       90, 90], dtype=int64)
data2['Value']=a
```

Comment: Impressive answer as always, one sidenote. You should replace `df` in the line of `a=...` with `data1`

Comment: @Erfan yep forgot replace that one :-)

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what you do with `np.dot` here? I am quite interested since I face this quite often.

Comment: @Erfan `dot` is matrix multiple and sum(Basically if you have a (n,m) and a (m,1) array, the out put will be (n,1) array ) , since we broadcast the data1 's times , then we will have a n*m matrix as result , True when satisfied both conditions , `dot` just do multiple 
 with every row in new matrix which shape is (n,1)

Comment: That worked. I did one small edit to eliminate adding two same time periods (where end time of last entry is same as start time next entry. `a=np.dot((s[:,None]>=s1)&(s[:,None]<s2),data1.Value.values)`